# HTML Forms in ASP.NET Web Pages gives errors CS0103 & CS1061

Tags: c#, razor

I have no previous experience with C# and .NET so I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms) tutorial to create an HTML form for some practice.
It says on the page, *At the top of the Form.cshtml file, enter the following code:*

```
@{
    if (IsPost) {
        string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
        string contactname = Request.Form["contactname"];
        int employeecount = Request.Form["employees"].AsInt();

        <text>
          You entered: <br />
          Company Name: @companyname <br />
          Contact Name: @contactname <br />
          Employee Count: @employeecount <br />
        </text>
    }
}
```

However, no matter where I place this piece of code on the page it gives me errors on **(IsPost)** (CS0103), that *The name 'isPost' does not exist in the current context* and **AsInt()** (CS1061), *'StringValue' does not contain a definition for 'AsInt' and no accessible extension method 'AsInt' accepting a first argument of type 'StringValue' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)..*

I'm not familiar with C# syntax but I thought this would be simple since it's literally like two steps in the tutorial, but somehow, I manage to fail with it anyways. I've Googled the errors and like mentioned I've tried to place the code snippet above in different places, but I have a hard time seeing still why it does not work.

Below is the code in full. Someone with more knowledge that can see why this isn't working?

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@{
    if (IsPost)
    {
        string companyname = Request.Form["companyname"];
        int employeecount = Request.Form["employees"].AsInt();

        <text>
            You entered: <br />
            Company Name: @companyname <br />
            Employee Count: @employeecount <br />
        </text>
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add Customer</legend>
            <div>
                <label for="CompanyName">Company Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Employees">Employee Count:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Employees" value="" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is for Asp.Net Framework 4.X as indicated at the top of the tutorial page. Specifically, Asp.Net Web Pages Razor 3. However, you have most likely created a Project for Asp.Net Core (6) which does not support the IsPost property. This may most likely be why the compiler is giving you the error message. To fix that error, you might be able to substitute `if(Model.FormPosted)` to check to see if the form has been submitted. However, you may want to take a step back start by establishing which version of Asp.Net you want to learn.  If you have a specific need to learn Framework 4.X then you probably want to open Visual Studio and choose File>New Project and find the Asp.Net Framework 4.X template and start over with that tutorial you had been following.
But if you are primarily wanting to learn how to create a new Asp.Net website, then you may want to start with Asp.Net Core as it is the newer technology meant to replace Framework 4, and is being more actively developed by Microsoft.
[Here is the documentation for Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials)

Comment: Thanks! I just posted a similar solution after realizing it's probably version issues causing the error, used `if (HttpMethods.IsPost(Request.Method))`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to error **CS0103**:

I think isPost is not a method of Razor pages (?), which seems to have caused the error. After more Googling around it worked by changing `if (isPost)` to the following:

```
if (HttpMethods.IsPost(Request.Method))
```